# Pass an Array as function parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

My question might be a little off as I'm new to Javascript but I was wondering why my array doesn't work the way I want it to work.

This is my function to fill array with data:
(Works perfect, console.log gives me the values I need which are in the picture below.)

```
async function readEngineerNames() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Engineers"));
    var EngineerNames = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      EngineerNames.push(doc.id); 
    });
    console.log(EngineerNames);
    AddEngineerNamesToList.apply(null, EngineerNames);
}
```

[image: Console shows me the array]

My function to receive the array:
(I can't retrieve the array. It either sends only the first element or the first element by letters)

```
        function AddEngineerNamesToList(EngineerNames) {
            var EName = EngineerNames.split(" ");
            console.log(EName);
            for (i = 0; i < EngineerNames.length; i++) {
                console.log(EngineerNames[i])
            }
        }
```

[image: What I get when I do console.log(EName)]

[image: What I get when I do console.log(EngineerNames[i]]

Can you guys please guide me on what I'm doing wrong. Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Multiple things nothing worked out. Just need the elements in the array one by one. Also if I pass a, b, c in the function AddEngineerstoList I can see the elements I need but my array is dynamically updated so I can't add a var everytime. Please ask me for more details if needed and hope my question makes sense. Thank you again

Comment: `AddEngineerNamesToList` doesn't make sense `EngineerNames.split(" ")` implies that the argument should be a string. But the `for` loop seems to be for an array.

Comment: `EngineerNames` is already an array. Call `AddEngineerNamesToList(EngineerNames)` and get rid of that `.split()`. You've made it more complicated than it really is.

Comment: You also don't need `apply`. That's for spreading an array into separate arguments. Also, in ES6 this can be written as `AddEngineerNamesToList(...EngineerNames)`

Comment: @Barmar yes I understood my mistake now, thank you. I'm not using apply anymore as it was very different than what I wanted to use it for. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Pointy I'm new to this. I would like to say WOW that was exactly what I was looking for but I just couldn't understand how to until now. I'm using this way now THANK YOUUUU